# How to test if a string contains one of multiple substrings?

Tags: string, powershell, compare

I wish to know if a string contains one of `abc`, `def`, `xyz`, etc. I could do it like:

```
$a.Contains("abc") -or $a.Contains("def") -or $a.Contains("xyz")
```

Well it works, but I have to change code if this substring list changes, and the performance is poor because `$a` is scanned multiple times.

Is there a more efficient way to do this with just one function call?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the -match method and create the regex automatically using string.join:

```powershell
$referenz = @('abc', 'def', 'xyz')    
$referenzRegex = [string]::Join('|', $referenz) # create the regex
```

Usage:

```powershell
"any string containing abc" -match $referenzRegex # true
"any non matching string" -match $referenzRegex #false
```

Comment: This snippet fails when the text contains especial regular expression characters. You must use `$referenzRegex = [string]::Join('|', [Regex]::Escape($referenz)) # create the regex` for this work.

Answer (score 3):

Regex it:  **$a -match /\a|def|xyz|abc/g**
(https://regex101.com/r/xV6aS5/1)

- Match exact characters anywhere in the original string:
  'Ziggy stardust' -match 'iggy'

source: http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html